# Ruby Net::HTTP.start giving connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a ruby class in which I am making Net::HTTP.start call inside perform method.This is the code:

```
class Poller

def self.perform(args)
uri = URI('http://localhost:8081/adhoc/dummy_poll?noAuth=true')
begin
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :read_timeout=>30) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
    @response = http.request request
    @responsecode = @response.code
  end
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.error "error mess==>"+e.message()
  @responsecode = "408"
end
```

When I enqueue this within `resque` from another class using this line:

```
Resque.enqueue_in_with_queue(:data_workflow_manager,10,Poller,args)
```

I get this error:

**Connection refused - connect(2) for "::1" port 8081.**

However, HTTP.start works fine without any errors when the perform method is called in some another class using:

```
    Poller.perform(args)
```

Please help me understand, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

try explicitly connecting to the loop back address. There may be resolution issues with localhost.

```
uri = URI('http://127.0.0.1:8081/adhoc/dummy_poll?noAuth=true')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you do not have any server running on `port 8081` which is why the connection will be refused.
Check it with `lsof -i` and look for programs bound to 8081 on a linux machine.

Comment: Server is running fine.I have tried hitting the same url.And I am able to hit using direct call.

Comment: To be clear, is the problem when you use it Directly, or when you use it with Resque? The wording of your question wasn't clear for me on that.

Comment: The problem is when I use it with Resque.